# How can I know if a process is running background or foreground in commans "ps" or "ps -ef"?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I know if a process is running background or foreground in commans "ps" or "ps -ef" ?

I first thought that when I type in ps -ef , there is a section named TTY.

when I look into the list of TTY, most of them are '?' (question marks)

I wonder if that question mark means process running background

I want to check if I am right!

If not, I want to know how I can know if the process is running background or foreground

ps. commnand "jobs" is not used here

Comment: This question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I believe it is correct to here. I would change the title. How to identify background process in a script.

Comment: https://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/256605-list-all-background-processes.html

Comment: The bar is higher than adding *"in a script"* to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I like this question and have a twisted solution for listing `ps` information about the background jobs/processes.

By definition of a job/background process. They are lists with `jobs -l` command.

1. Store the background jobs pid in a list

   ```
   echo "$(jobs -l)" | awk '{print $2}' > jobs.lst
   ```
2. Intersect the jobs list with current process

   ```
   ps -eo pid,args | grep -f jobs.lst
   ```

The output is `ps -eo pid,args` result for background jobs.

Providing the id and the command line arguments for the background jobs.

**P.S**

I used `ps` output option `-o` to list only `pid` and `args`. Change it to your liking, but make sure `pid` is there.